# Why does it means to be that solutions of polynomial are symmetric?

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation, galois-theory

I am reading an overview on Galois theory. It is mentioned that solutions are symmetric, for example, what I understood that  if one solution/zero of $f(x)$ is $(a+1)$ ($a$ is a cconstant) then another solution would be  $(-a-1)$?  Why do we assume solutions of polynomial are symmetric? If  one solution is $(a+1)$ then  why could't  $(2a-1)$  be a another solution? If $(2a-1)$ a solution, then does it mean $(-2a-1)$ has to be a solution also ? why?

Why does it means to be that  solutions of polynomial are symmetric (please provide example if I am wrong in above)? Why don't we consider the possibility  asymmetric solution? Please refer to the theorem, no need to provide the proof here.

Comment: This is just the definition of even functions : $f(-x)=f(x)$ for every real $x$. But how is this related to Galois theory ?